# Silverlight application - which is the service and is it running when the site is closed?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I've made a silverlight application, with 2 projects in it, a projectname and then a projectname.web but which one will run on the IIS while no one is visiting the site? 
or will they both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projectname.xap file will be downloaded from the web server's ClientBin directory to the visitor's web browser, and will run on his computer. If your silverlight application makes any web service (WCF, etc.) calls to the projectname.web Web Application, then during the lifetime of these calls the projectname.web will run, but will otherwise sit idle -- unless you have some code in your projectname.web which keeps running in the background regardless of whether requests are made.

Comment: okay, so if i have like a loop/timer etc. in the .web project, it will always run ?

Comment: Well it will run until IIS recycles the application pool. On a default installation I believe the recycle time is 20 minutes. After 20 minutes (or longer if you adjust the value) IIS will kill the process. Generally speaking your application should be well prepared to handle such an event.